# Why is my for loop condition not satisfied?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out for hours why my program does not enter the for loop. In the main function, I assigned 4 to the parameter n, so the condition "`i <= n`" should be satisfied. I checked and the program enters the else block. Current output = in else 5

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int series(int n){
    
    int result = 5;
    if(n = 0){
       return 1;
       
    }else{  
      
       for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
           cout << "in loop ";
       }  
      
    cout << "in else "; 
    return result;
    }

              
}


int main()
{
   cout << series(4);
   return 0;
}
```

Can anyone see why it doesn't work?

Comment: `if(n = 0){ `is an assignment. You set n to 0 then check if its not zero you will return. But you set it to 0. Your compiler should warn against this.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put `n == 0` instead your `n = 0` clause of the `if` sentence. That should do it.

What's happening is:

1. You're calling `series` function with a 4 parameter
2. This parameter (stored in variable `n`) is assigned the `0` value in this part of your code:

   if (n = 0)
3. In `C`, the assignment expression (like `n = 0`) returns the value being assigned. In this case, `0`. So the `else` part of your code **will ALWAYS execute**.
4. Even though the `else` part will **ALWAYS EXECUTE**, the `for` loop will not run not even once because `i <= n` is **false**.